# Instance variable stays null when using Mockito

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I have the following class

```
package pckt.theclass;

public class TheClass {

    public String name = "testing";

    public void setTheName(){
        this.name = getNamesFromDB();
    }

    public String getNamesFromDB(){
        return "pablo";
    }

}
```

And this is the test class for it

```
package pckt.theclass;

import org.junit.*;
import org.mockito.Mockito;


public class TheClassTest {

    @Test
    public void testSetTheName() {

        //TheClass tc = Mockito.mock(TheClass.class);
        //Mockito.when(tc.getNamesFromDB()).thenReturn("dbName");
        TheClass tc = new TheClass();
        tc.setTheName();
        System.out.println("Name: "+tc.name);
        Assert.assertEquals("pablo", tc.name);
    }
}
```

If I run the test class as it is, it passes. However, if I uncomment the Mockito lines and modify assertEquals to expect "dbName" the test fails with the error

```
expectend "dbName" but was <null>
```

The issue is because the instance variable "name" is not being populated for some reason, even if it already has a value on its declaration. i'm new to Mockito so I'm not sure if I need to do something for this to work.

Thoughts?

Comment: You should first ask yourself (and answer) why you are mocking the class you're trying to test.

Comment: I see nothing to mock.  Everything is supplied in that class and can be tested easily.  If you *did* mock this, you'd *really* be lying to yourself.

Comment: This is a test, while I Was reading about Mockito I decided to create a small test to understand its functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because if you declare `TheClass tc` instance to be a mock, `setTheName`'s body is no longer the one you defined in `TheClass`, but a stub method that returns `null`. This is because you didn't "train" `setTheName` to have any behaviour.

Effectively the mocked instance looks as if it was declared like this:

```java
public class TheClass {
    public String name = null;

    public void setTheName(){
        // do nothing
    }

    public String getNamesFromDB(){
        return "dbName";
    }
}
```

You're making one of the basic Mockito mistakes: you're mocking the system under test.

Comment: I misunderstood the purpose of Mockito and this was just a very basic test to understand how it works. I'll mock another class and provide an implementation for the methods and see how it goes.